# How to create TCP/IP loadbalancer/applicationgateway for Azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

1. I have an Azure Kubernetes Cluster.
2. I have created the TCP/IP server as a service and deployed it in the same cluster.
3. I have other .net core multiple microservices deployed in the same cluster.
4. Now I want to create the application gateway/Loadbalancer/ingress, which supports the TCP/IP request.

Does anybody have any suggestions? 
As I know Applicationgateway/ingress supports only HTTP/S but not TCP/IP, anybody has any suggestions, I want to use the TCP/requests, not the HTTP/S...

Answer (score 1):

nginx ingress [supports](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) tcp\udp ingress.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  9000: "default/example-go:8080"
```

Load balancer also supports tcp requests, so that combination would work

Comment: I tried using the istio-ingressgateway with virtual service for routing.

Comment: But under the istio-ingressgateway service, i don't see my ports. Its still only shows it's default ports exposed (kubectl get service -n istio-system). I manually edited the service by using the command - kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system.  And then i see my ports. I created the virtual service adding the source host/port and destinationation in the yaml file, and deployed it. I see Virtual service also got created.

Comment: But I am unable to hit the Istiogateway from TCP client or curl command for my ports. I can only able to see the connection for ports 80 and 443. Do you know what could be the reason for this ??. Actually i am going with nginx ingress approach. We have decided to got with IstioIngressGateway.

Comment: you are contradicting yourself, can you please edit the question so it reflects current state?